# Is it natural to say "thank you for staying on" when you get someone off hold on the phone?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Would you tell me if it is natural to say *thank you for staying on* when you get someone off hold on the phone?

I've never heard anyone saying that, but it seems to me it might be natural as it can be interpreted as short for *thank you for staying on the line*.

If it doesn't sound natural, would provide better alternatives?

Comment: The most natural thing I can think of is simply "Thank you for holding."

Comment: Or **for holding on**. although I've often heard **for staying on the line**.

Comment: @RonaldSole "holding on" to my Canadian ears sounds like "surviving despite adversity", as in, "My hockey team is terrible, but somehow we keep holding on."

Comment: *Anything* you say will likely be appreciated more than the music-on-hold to which the caller has been subjected ;-)

Comment: @gotube - given how long you frequently have to wait "for our next available agent", thanks for "holding on" is very appropriate!

Comment: @gotube As you say; On my many visits to your country, I've learned like, to try to talk Canadian.